# Java - Netbeans - No Main Class Found

Tags: java, class, netbeans

Now before you report this as a question that has already been asked, hear me out.

I have taken a look at all other questions and none of them are supplying the answer - I've tried all of them. In addition, they are all at least a year old, so I'm guessing the reason the answers don't work any more is because Netbeans must have updated.

So anyways, the problem is that I am getting the error: Project Class does not have a main class set.

I thought posting my code would help, so here it is:

```
package Class;

public class Bicycle 
{
    public int cadence;
    public int gear;
    public int speed;

    public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
        gear = startGear;
        cadence = startCadence;
        speed = startSpeed;
    }

    public void setCadence(int newValue) 
    {
        cadence = newValue;
    }

    public void setGear(int newValue) 
    {
        gear = newValue;
    }

    public void applyBrake(int decrement) 
    {
        speed -= decrement;
    }

    public void speedUp(int increment) 
    {
        speed += increment;
    }

    public class MountainBike extends Bicycle 
    {
        public int seatHeight;

        public MountainBike(int startHeight, int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) 
        {
            super(startCadence, startSpeed, startGear);
            seatHeight = startHeight;
        }

        public void setHeight(int newValue) 
        {
            seatHeight = newValue;
        }   
    }
}
```

And, yes, this is the sample code for classes on the java website. It's ironic, considering there's no class found... and my program is dealing with classes.

So anyways, I would like to know why it isn't working, and how I can fix this problem not just specifically for this code, but in general, so that whenever it may arise I am ready to tackle it.

Finally, if anyone feels that my question is not clear or I don't comply with the guidelines for asking a question on Stack Overflow, please let me know. I'll be more than happy to edit the question.

-CoolKat

Comment: I don't see a main method anywhere.  That's what it's complaining about.  You need `public static void main(String[] args)` in at least one of those files (or a completely different file) to execute anything in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no main file in your code. You can try making a *test* code in a completely new file to artificially create a main class. Or you could use `public static void main(String args[]) {` in your actual code and thus create a main class.